# Find items in table with 2 specific sizes

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have items table where the item code repeats as it has different sizes, variants.

I want to find items which has 2 specific sizes, ie size in both M/Y and Euro.

Items table:

```
Id size
1  0  
1  2Y
1  EU-15
2  2M
2  4M
3  0
3  2M-4M
3  EU-12
4  EU-11
4  EU-15
```

Required, I want to query for item id 1 and 3.

I was trying with SUM(), CASE but not able to figure it as it involves LIKE operator. `(Size like '[^EU]%' and Size like 'EU%')`

#Update:

With little hint, I could do it with 2 queries using temp table. Would be nice to see it in single query.

1st Query.

```
select id, 
case when size like '[^EU]%' then 'S' 
     when size like 'EU%' then 'EU' END as size 
     into #t from table
```

2nd Query.

```
select id, size from table
           where id in 
       ( select id from #t 
               group by id 
               having count(distinct(size))>1) 
order by id, size
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted Id with both `EU%` and non `EU%`

```
select t.Id
from   tbl t
group by t.Id
having count(distinct case when size like 'EU%' then 1 else 2 end) = 2
```

Comment: I could do it 2 queries. Updated Question. Can you modify that into single query?

Comment: That is what my query is doing now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function as follows:

```
select * from
(select t.*,
       count(case when Size like '%M' OR Size like '%Y' then 1 end)
             over (partition by id) cnt1,
       count(case when Size like 'EU%' then 1 end)
             over (partition by id) cnt2
   from your_Table t) t
where cnt1 > 0 AND cnt2 > 0
```

Comment: Not working. Updated the wildcard in question.

Comment: 1st Query. select id, case when size like '[^EU]%' then 'S' when size like 'EU%' then 'EU' END as size  into #t from table)
group by id

2nd Query. select id, size from table where id in (
select id from #t
group by id
having count(distinct(size))>1)
order by id, size

Comment: I could do it in 2 queries now using temp table.